# How to retrieve 'double' values saved under one key in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, classcastexception, geofire

I have stored `Geofire` coordinates in database and now I'm trying to retrieve them using `childEventListener()` like this:

```
    mDatabase.child("geofire").child(key).child("l").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                                        //error on line below
                                                        Map<Double, Double> newRequest = (Map<Double, Double>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                                        venueLatString = newRequest.get(0).toString();
                                                        venueLngString = newRequest.get(1).toString();
                                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NULLL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ...
                                                ...
                                            });
```

Geofire coordnates are stored in database like this:

[image]

I'm getting this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.util.Map` on line specified above.

**What is going wrong here** and why am I getting this error?

Please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to get the whole geolocation or just the specific double values?

Comment: specific double values... as already shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `addChildEventListener`, the `DataSnapshot` produced is from the child node of the referenced node. So in your case, your ref node is `l`, then inside `onChildAdded`, the `dataSnapshot` is :

- key `0` with value `28.8...`
- key `1` with value `78.7...`

So the `onChidAdded()` will be called twice.

You can modify your code based on that logic or use `addValueEventListener` instead. And if you use `addValueEventListener`, your code will be like this:

```
mDatabase.child("geofire").child(key).child("l").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
            Double d1 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue();
            Double d2 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue();

            venueLatString = String.valueOf(d1);
            venueLngString = String.valueOf(d2);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NULLL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    ...
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: getting this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map` after using `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: Do you really need it to be `Map` object or `List` is okay? I'll edit my answer based on your need

Comment: I just need to assign respective values to respective strings which are `venueLatString` and `venueLngString`.

Comment: try this `venueLatString = dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue()` and change it to `1` for `venueLngString`

Comment: edit the answer with code from above comment of yours and I would accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please Try Following.

```
final HashMap<String, Object> taskMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) objectMap.getValue();
                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(taskMap.get("0"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(taskMap.get("1"));
```

Comment: this error now: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap`.

Comment: any improvements to be made?

Answer (score 0):

```
mDatabase.child("geofire").child(key).child("l").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double latati = 0, longit = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
//                    Log.e("!! All Data ::> ", child.getKey()+" "+child.getValue());
                    if (child.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                        latati = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(child.getValue()));
                    }
                    if (child.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        longit = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(child.getValue()));
                    }
                }
                Log.e("!_@@__Lat Long ::", latati + " " + longit);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("!!__: ", "onCancelled ", firebaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```