# Cast String data type to double in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm get data from dataSnapshot Firebase. My data all is String. I can get data but can't cast String to double, if I cast, my app will stop. Please help me.

```
 mReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String strName=(String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
            String strphone=(String) dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue();
            String lati=(String) dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
            String longti=(String) dataSnapshot.child("longtitude").getValue();
            String strDiemden=(String) dataSnapshot.child("diemden").getValue();

          // double lati=Double.parseDouble(strLat);
           // double longti=Double.parseDouble(strLong);
            ;
          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati,longti)).title(strName));
```

Comment: It's impossible to say what's going wrong without seeing the JSON that you're trying to parse (as actual JSON text please, no screenshot). While you're at it, please also include the stack trace of the error that you get.

Comment: Thank for reply, I solved it. my problem is Firebase returned null value ( my values all not null), 'cause the value is null, I can't cast  and then I used Map to put values instead use constructor, I can cast

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41691634/1343788

Answer (score 1):

can you please try this.

```
Double d1 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
        Double d2 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("longtitude").getValue();

        String venueLatString = String.valueOf(d1);
        String venueLngString = String.valueOf(d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that **value is null or not**
then use this

double l =Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(child.getValue()));

or

`double l = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue())`;