# Get Double From Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a double from firebase object using dataSnapshot but each time I try to, I'm getting an error saying that `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double` and when I try to maybe Cast it to a Long just to observe what's gonna happen I get this Error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`, so in short the error is vice versa. This is the code I'm using to get my total in Firebase dataSnapshot:

```
 mDatabaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (!isPrinted) {
                System.out.println("Children" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Double price = (Double) snapshot.child("total").getValue();
                    System.out.println("Price: " + String.valueOf(price));
                }
                isPrinted = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

and this is the code I'm using to save the total on firebase:

```
double total = holder.quantity * price;
                   dataSnapshot.child(code).child("total").getRef().setValue(total);
```

I'm looking to retrieve the total from firebase using `Double` but it gives me the `ClassCastException`. Please help with a solution.
I also tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691463/how-to-retrieve-double-values-saved-under-one-key-in-firebase#) for a solution but did not find anything

This is my FirebaseDatabase where I'm querying from: [image]

Comment: Since you're getting both types of `ClassCastException`s, I think the problem is that node from which you're trying to retrieve data has a few children that are `Long`, and other children that are `Double`. Please post your Database structure.

Comment: @Rohan Stark. I just posted it now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I can see the problem from your Database Screenshot. You have one `total` node's value as "5.16". While, another `total`'s value is "0" (I also assume that you have a lot more `total` nodes with values as "0").

So, you're getting a `ClassCastException` no matter what you do because "5.16" is treated as a `Double`, while "0" is treated as a `Long` - and you're retrieving both in the same query.

The simplest solution is to change your "0" to "0.0". This would make all `total` nodes hold `Double` values. Then, you just have to call the following to retrieve the value :-

```
Double price = (Double) snapshot.child("total").getValue();
```

Comment: Great! All the best

Comment: How do I store 0.0 instead of 0? When I write `.setValue(0.0)` or `.setValue(new Double(0.0))` it's still stored as a Long with the value 0.

Answer (score 2):

I am a newbie and might be wrong, I was facing the same issue today and the only workaround I could find was this.

```
// I am trying to convert the required data
// I use Kotlin Langauage

fun getData(snapshot: DataSnapshot) : Double{

    val a :Any? = snapshot.child("required_data").value

    val b : Double = if(a != null && a.toString() != "0"){ 
        a as Double
     } else 0.0
    return b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because 0 is treated and stored as Long, not Double. To make code work in both cases, do:

```
double val = 0;
Number num = (Number) snapshot.child("total").getValue();
if (num != null) {
    val = num.doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Top answer uses a trick but we can instead use the class `Number`. It gives a one liner which is a lot cleaner:

```kotlin
val myDouble = (snapshot.child("data").value as Number).toDouble()
```

if you want to handle `null` values as well:

```kotlin
val myDouble = (snapshot.child("data").value as Number?)?.toDouble()
// myDouble: Double?
```

or coalesce to a default value:

```kotlin
val myDouble = (snapshot.child("data").value as Number?)?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
```

Or if you want a function to do the work:

```kotlin
fun getData(snapshot: DataSnapshot, defaultValue: Double = 0.0): Double {
    return (snapshot.value as Number?)?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
}
```

Note that it will still crash if the data is not number-based.